# Output of Rows in Columns ad let other columns away in SQL Developer in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL and I am struggling with the task to make a particular output of an oracle database data.

I need some rows to be transformed into columns and to put it togheter with just some chosen columns I need.
The thing is I have to do this task on a lot of tabels and I just don't find a way to do it. I guess you as pros have to deal with something like this on a daily basis so maybe you could help me out on that. It would make me very happy.

Here is my table in the db:

```
PRODUCTTXTID    PRODUCTID   COMID   TXTNUMMER   LANG    TXT
0740000000005D  0740000000002P  254 1   DE  German text1 of this article
0740000000005I  0740000000002P  254 1   IT  Italian text1 of this article
0740000000005F  07400000000EPF  254 2   DE  German text2 of this article
07400000000F03  074000000007L8  254 1   DE  German text1 of this article
0740000000005D  074000000007L8  254 2   IT  Italian text2 of this article
07400000000F05  074000000007L9  254 1   DE  German text1 of this article
0740000000001S  0740000000000X  254 1   DE  German text1 of this article
0740000000001T  0740000000000X  254 1   IT  Italian text1 of this article
0740000000001U  0740000000000Y  254 2   DE  German text2 of this article
0740000000001V  0740000000000Y  254 1   IT  Italian text1 of this article
07400000000F07  074000000007LA  254 1   DE  German text1 of this article
```

I need to take it out like this:

```
PRODUCTID               TXT1DE                      TXT1IT                          TXT2DE                      TXT2IT
0740000000002P  German text1 of this article    Italian text1 of this article   German text2 of this article    Italian text2 of this article
0740000000002A  German text1 of this article    Italian text1 of this article   German text2 of this article    Italian text2 of this article
07400000000EPF  German text1 of this article    Italian text1 of this article   German text2 of this article    Italian text2 of this article
074000000007L7  German text1 of this article    Italian text1 of this article   German text2 of this article    Italian text2 of this article
074000000007L8  German text1 of this article    Italian text1 of this article   German text2 of this article    Italian text2 of this article
074000000007L9  German text1 of this article    Italian text1 of this article   German text2 of this article    Italian text2 of this article
0740000000000E  German text1 of this article    Italian text1 of this article   German text2 of this article    Italian text2 of this article
0740000000000X  German text1 of this article    Italian text1 of this article   German text2 of this article    Italian text2 of this article
0740000000000Y  German text1 of this article    Italian text1 of this article   German text2 of this article    Italian text2 of this article
0740000000000A  German text1 of this article    Italian text1 of this article   German text2 of this article    Italian text2 of this article
074000000007LA  German text1 of this article    Italian text1 of this article   German text2 of this article    Italian text2 of this article
```

best regards,
matt

Comment: How many languages and numbers can you have? If you have a limit to these values, say 2 languages and 2 numbers, as in you sample data, you may use a PIVOT. If these values are unlimited, plain SQL will not be enough, given that you would need a query with a variable number of resulting columns

Comment: Also, in you sample data you have, for example, 2 rows for productId = '0740000000002P', but in your result you show 4 different texts for the same id; can you clarify this?

Comment: There are only 2 languages and only 2 text numbers, that is right.
All combinations are in 4 rows. These 4 rows should ge 1 row with 4 columns. each column for one text (txt1DE, txt1IT, txt2De, txt2IT)

Answer (score 0):

If you've limited distinct values in TXTNUMMER and LANG and your Oracle version is 11g or newer, the simple PIVOT should do just what you need. You just need to hardcode the possible values in IN clause of PIVOT. For example, on sample data:

```
WITH TST AS
(SELECT '0740000000002P' PRODUCTID, 254 COMID, 1 TXTNUMMER, 'DE' LANG, 'German text1 of this article' TXT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0740000000002P' PRODUCTID, 254 COMID, 1 TXTNUMMER, 'IT' LANG, 'Italian text1 of this article' TXT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '07400000000EPF' PRODUCTID, 254 COMID, 2 TXTNUMMER, 'DE' LANG, 'German text2 of this article' TXT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '074000000007L8' PRODUCTID, 254 COMID, 1 TXTNUMMER, 'DE' LANG, 'German text1 of this article' TXT FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '074000000007L8' PRODUCTID, 254 COMID, 2 TXTNUMMER, 'IT' LANG, 'Italian text2 of this article' TXT FROM DUAL)
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT PRODUCTID, 'TXT' || TXTNUMMER || LANG LANGID, TXT FROM TST)
     PIVOT 
(MAX(TXT) FOR LANGID IN ('TXT1DE','TXT1IT','TXT2DE','TXT2IT'))
```

Otherwise, if the number of languages is not predefined, there is no general solution, because Oracle doesn't like unknown number of columns in result set. However, some pl/sql function, which will generate the temp table and fill it with data using dynamic sql should do the trick.

Comment: thank you. I have got 2 diffrent values in TXTNUMMER - "1" and "2"
and I have got 2 diffrent values in SPRID - "DE" and "IT"